# Cards in grid not adjusting their heights as wanted

Tags: html, css, reactjs, grid, tailwind-css

I am using Tailwind with React and I have a grid that looks like this currently.
[image]

```
<div className="grid xl:grid-cols-4 lg:grid-cols-3 md:grid-cols-2 grid-cols-1 place-items-center gap-4">
            {cards.map((card) => (
              <div
                className="h-[auto] w-[320px] px-2 pt-2 pb-4 rounded-md border-2 border-gray-200"
                key={card.id}
              >
                <div className="relative rounded-xl overflow-hidden">
                  <img src={card.image} alt="fund1" />
                  <div className="absolute top-4 uppercase right-4 leading-tight font-bold w-[70px] h-[70px] flex items-center justify-center bg-white text-black rounded-full text-[11px] text-center">
                    Discover your match
                  </div>
                </div>
                <article className="px-2">
                  <h2 className="font-bold text-[25px] hover:text-[#6D9886] transition-colors cursor-pointer my-4">
                    {card.topic}
                  </h2>
                  <p className="font-light text-[14px]">{card.text}</p>
                  <button className="block mx-auto text-[#6D9886] mt-6">
                    Read more
                  </button>
                </article>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
```

Now, The height of the cards is not balanced from top as I want it straight. Also from bottom of the cards, I want the other cards to adjust as soon as one's height ends.
Here is what I want to achieve:
[image]

I have tried setting differed columns and rows properties from grid but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
If you are using Bootstrap you will get


<div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-4">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is a short card.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>enter code here
</div>


or if you are using simple css just give a class and give that class to every part
```

Comment: I can't use bootstrap currently and would love a css solution if any.